# How to Reference Web.xml's Context Param Inside Web.xml Itself?

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, init-parameters

Assume that there is a context parameter defined inside web deployment descriptor:

```
  <context-param>
     <param-name>initParam</param-name>
     <param-value>initParamValue</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

How can I use this parameter inside web.xml itself, e.g. ${initParam} or something?

```
  <context-param>
     <param-name>otherParam</param-name>
     <param-value>(use initParam here)-otherParamValue</param-value>
  </context-param>
```